# Why is my list not refreshing?

Tags: java, android, list

I have a file list and when the user saves a file I want to refresh the list so the new file shows up. This is what I've tried.

```
private IconifiedTextListAdapter itla = new IconifiedTextListAdapter(this);
```

...

```
private void saveAs(){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.setTitle("Save as");
                alert.setMessage("(Will be saved in the current working directory)");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String value = input.getText().toString();
                  String tmpText = et.getText().toString();

                  try {
                    File tempfile = new File(currentDirectory, value);
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempfile);
                      writer.write(tmpText);
                      writer.flush();
                      writer.close();
                      changed=false; 
                      itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  }
                });
```

Comment: You never seem to use the adapter further (eg getting/adding to it). I don't think there's anything to refresh.

Comment: Thanks :) I call fill() to populate the list in onCreate() but forgot to call it again in saveAs() I feel stupid.

Comment: Please add the answer and mark it as solved, it can help others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void saveAs(final Intent intent) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Save as");
    alert.setMessage("(Will be saved in the current working directory)");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(ending);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            String tmpText = et.getText().toString();
            if (!value.contains(".")) {
                value = value + ending;
            }

            try {
                File tempfile = new File(currentDirectory, value);
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempfile);
                writer.write(tmpText);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                changed = false;
                exists = true;
                String newFile = new File(currentDirectory + "//" + value)
                        .getPath();
                currentFile = new File(newFile);
                fill(currentDirectory.listFiles());
                Log.i("saveAs", currentFile.getPath());
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same way as in a question - use the button that does it automagically or add 4 spaces in front of each line of code. I went ahead and did it for you though :)